# How to open a page directly in a browser having a post data

Tags: c#, .net, post

We can open a page using a query string(GET data) directly in a brower.
Is there any way to open a page directly in a browser having POST DATA.

Comment: Do you want to do that from a WinForms/WPF app or from a ASP.NET page?

Comment: I doesn't want it from programming point of view. I just want to know is it possible to open directly using browser as we are doing in GET method by passing a query string

Comment: BUT that makes the difference. So HOW do you want to call this? In theory it IS possible, but if it is actually possible depends on the "how"...

Comment: I don't really understand you, the only way I can think of is launching the browser and then hook into it and send the post data? But I don't even know if you talk about a third party browser or the browser component in .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You open the url with post data by using WebBrowser control :

```
  string url = "http://example.com";  
  string postData = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
  byte[] Post = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData );  
  string AdditionalHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
  //wbSample is the web browser control  
  //the WebNavigate method is just a simple method i created  
  //which simply assigns url to the browser, the post data and additional headers  
  WebNavigate(wbSample , ListURL, "", Post, AdditionalHeaders);
```